# Unit test method doesn't recognize app conf connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have been working on ASP.NET MVC project Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Entity Framework. I have to include a Unit Test project into my solution. My problem is in that the test method (called Index()) can't recognize the application connection string in app.config. My Unit test method is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ELSORegistry;
using ELSORegistry.DataAccess;
using ELSORegistry.Controllers;



namespace ELSORegistryUnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class FirstControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Index()
        {
            //Arange
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();

            //Act
            Guid? myGuid = new Guid("941b1615-f21b-4e2c-8fa8-0ed0d3f2de53");
            ViewResult result = controller.Index(myGuid) as ViewResult;

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
    }
}
```

My Index() action in the Home Controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ELSORegistry.DataAccess;
using ELSORegistry.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using WebGrease.Css.Extensions;
using ELSORegistry.Extensions;



using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ELSORegistry.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace ELSORegistry.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "ECLS Center Data Manager, ECLS Center Administrator,ECLS Center Data Viewer, ECLS Center Data Entry")]
        //[RequireHttps]  // Enable for production
        public ActionResult Index(Guid? CenterId)
        {
            //----------------------------------------
            // Remove references to previous patients
            //----------------------------------------    
            Session.Remove("Patient");
            Session.Remove("PatientSummary");
            Session.Remove("Run");
            Session.Remove("RunDetail");
            Session.Remove("Addendum");

            // if user have this session then he will get edit forms. // Yes if Add new
            Session.Remove("AddNewMode");
            Session.Remove("AddNewRunId");
            Center center;
            if (CenterId == null)
            {
                center = Session["Center"] as Center;
                Contract.Assert(center != null);
            }
            else
            { // set center by selected centerId from dropdownlist
                center = new Repository().GetCenter(new Guid(CenterId.ToString()));
                Session["Center"] = center;
                center = Session["Center"] as Center;
                Contract.Assert(center != null);
            }


            ViewBag.RunCounts = Session["RunCounts"];
            ViewBag.ChartSummaries = Session["ChartSummaries"];



            return View(new QuickAdd());

        }
```

The bug is in the line:

```
center = new Repository().GetCenter(new Guid(CenterId.ToString()));
```

of the controller. The method GetCenter is:

```
public Center GetCenter(Guid centerId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new ELSORegistryEntities())
                {
                    var center = context.Centers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CenterId == centerId);
                    return center;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                throw new DataException(string.Format("Error retrieving center for CenterId {0}", centerId), ex);
            }
        }
```

and app.config is in the ELSORegistry.DataAccess project which is included in the test. The class ELSORegistryEntities() is:

```
namespace ELSORegistry.DataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class ELSORegistryEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ELSORegistryEntities()
            : base("name=ELSORegistryEntities")
        {            
        }
```

The connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ELSORegistryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NELAPC\NELA2014;initial catalog=ELSORegistry2;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

***The bug is : "Test method ELSORegistryUnitTests.FirstControllerTest.Index throw exception:System.Data.DataException:Error retrieving center for CenterId 941b1615-f21b-4e2c-8fa8-0ed0d3f2de53->System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named'ELSORegistryEntities' could be found in the application config file".*** How can I solve this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your test project needs an _app.config_ with a connection string.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is right.

Comment: This is not a unit test! Unit tests do not use your database. They mock them and you should be using a mocking framework (for example [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include an app.config file inside you unit test project.  Only the running project's (in this case the unit test project) app.config is respected/used.